# Replacing text in JQuery UI Grid Selectable with a new one

Tags: indexing, grid, html-lists, each, selectable

I am using http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid with option for multi selection like I am doing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269438/how-can-i-select-and-deselect-multiple-grid-icons-in-javascript-and-show-the-sel

Can anyone explain why I can replace the "title" text Info-2 but not the text Info-1 inside the li marks!

```
<li class="ui-state-default" title="Info-2">Info-1</li>
```

This one is working fine:

```
$('li').each(function(index, temp){ $(temp).attr('title', ar[index+1][kLan] ); });
```

But not this one:

```
$('li').each(function(index2, temp2){ 
    var tmp = $(temp2).text();
    $(temp2).attr(tmp, ar[index2+1][kLan] ); });
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I GET:

***jquery-1.9.1.js:2358INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5: An invalid or illegal character was specified, such as in an XML name.***

Answer (score 0):

I found out of this problem by myself:

```
$('li').each(function(index, temp){ $(temp).html(ar[index+1][kLan] ); });
```

And now all is working fine!